# good book for wsdl, web services and php soap?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'd like to learn web services (SOAP, WSDL) and I primarily code in PHP.  Can you suggest any book, that uses PHP to teach these concepts?

Comment: Just to comment, you might want to look into restful services.  It doesn't use a WSDL or SOAP messages.  You basically use http verbs to start certain actions on the service.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try W3SCHOOLS first it can get you started off pretty quickly, [WSDL](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/default.asp) and [SOAP](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp)

Comment: I'd like to add that the PHP.net documentation is also a great documentation once you've understood what SOAP is. http://php.net/soap

Answer (score 3):

O'Reilly's [PHP Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101015) has two chapters with good examples.

[Ch 14 - Consuming Web Services](http://books.google.ca/books?id=P1wJRrE8KjYC&lpg=PR17&dq=php%20cookbook%20chapter%2014&pg=PA441#v=onepage&q&f=false)
[Ch 15 - Building Web Services](http://books.google.ca/books?id=P1wJRrE8KjYC&lpg=PR17&dq=php%20cookbook%20chapter%2015&pg=PA463#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Also http://www.packtpub.com/toc/php-oracle-web-development-data-processing-security-caching-xml-web-services-and-ajax-table-cont#chapter_9 this book has a good example about building SOAP server and SOAP client that consumes it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this nice book: "[Zend Framework Web Services](http://www.phparch.com/books/zend-framework-web-services/)"
It covers SOAP, RPC, REST, JSON-RPC and a range of other adjacent development topics, including web services testing.